# JQuery function to allow only alphabets in textbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following JQuery function to restrict users from writing numeric values in the textbox. The code works fine but the problem is that it also restrict users from using other characters like full stop(.), comma(,), $, @ and other signs..It also does not allow users to use the options of copy and past. I only want to restrict the users from writing numeric values or numbers but the user should be allowed to use other characters.

```
$(function() {
  $('.txtOnly').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      var key = e.keyCode;
      if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't need javascript at all. Just stick to the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute. The user is still free to type anything he wants, but the form validation will fail if the content is incorrect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="txtOnly" id="txtOnly" name="txtOnly" type="text" />
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( ".txtOnly" ).keypress(function(e) {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.txtOnly').keypress(function (e) {
   var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
   var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
   if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.error').show();
   $('.error').text('Please Enter Alphabate');
   return false;
   }
  });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p class="error"></p>
    <input class="txtOnly" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do using regex `/[^a-z]/g`

```js
$('.txtOnly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="lorem" class="txtOnly">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use following code snippet to prevent users from entering numeric input. It will check for each `keydown` event and prevent any subsequent action if numeric value is provided.

```js
$('.txtOnly').bind('keydown', function(event) {
  var key = event.which;
  if (key >=48 && key <= 57) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="txtOnly">
```